# Bootstrap select doesn't update selected options properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I am using bootstrap select plugin, When the options at bottom of the select is selected the bootstrap select does not  refresh the select properly(the previously selected options remains as selected as the boostrap select does not remove the selected class properly), 
Do I have to listen the change event on bootstrap select and refresh the options, This is not occurring while having lesser options, What mightbe the solution for this

```
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  });
```

Js fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/aarthi_101/79rz3j1w/18/,

I have posted an issue at github,
https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/85

[image: This is the result I am getting]

Comment: Your jsfiddle works fine and the previously selected option doesn't remain selected. Are you still having an issue with this?

Comment: Yes, Still having the issue, Can you try selecting the options at the bottom of the list of options

Comment: I have edited my question with added a screenshot of it. Please have a look

Answer (score 4):

Just refresh when change the select and it'll work well.
The code :

```
$('select').on('change',function(){

   $(this).selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

Comment: my case is, if the bootstrap select is not in active bootstrap tab(my page has 3 tabs) when page load complete, the select won't refresh after change event. This answer really helps me, thanks :)

Comment: @ChiaChi  I'm glad that my answer helped you  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h6dkgL35/

I added a script to remove the 'active' class from the previously selected option.

```
  $('.dropdown-item').on('click', function() {
  $('.dropdown-item').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  });
```

I also added a style because the newly selected option had a blue background instead of purple.

Comment: I can't able to get the results as you said in the fiddle. That issue still occurs